# Passing data attribute value into JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am retrieving the value of html tag in a JavaScript function, but right now if I wanted to retrieve the data attribute value of html and pass it in a JavaScript variable.

How can I do it?

```
// create a UL element
var ul = $('<ul></ul>');

// add some LI elements
ul.append(
    $('<li class="bear" data-type="panda">panda bear</li>'),
    $('<li class="bear" data-type="koala">koala bear</li>'),
    $('<li class="wallaby" data-type="kangaroo">kangaroo</li>')
);

// this won't work because our UL is not in the dom yet
console.log($('.bear').length); //=> 0

// let's just pick the bears in our UL using our UL as the context
var bears = $('.bear', ul);
console.log(bears); //=> [li.bear, li.bear]

// lets loop through and see data attributes
bears.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('data-type'));
});
//=> "panda"
//=> "koala"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are not using string concatenation here

```
statusHtmlArr.push('<li class="loc-li" data-test="' + rowData.APPT_LOC_QUAL[k].LOCATION_CD + '"  value="' + rowData.APPT_LOC_QUAL[k].LOCATION_CD + '"><a class="sub-detail" href="Javascript:void(0);">' + rowData.APPT_LOC_QUAL[k].LOCATION + '</a></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve an attribute of an element, it's easy by using jQuery.

```
$('#selectorId').attr('attribute name')
```

or

```
$('.className').attr('attribute name')
```

Comment: but how to pass it into js variable locID

Comment: `locID  = $('#selectorId').attr('attribute name');` because it returns a string result.

Comment: Here I am using a class and not an I'd so how can I do it

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var locID = $("li.loc-li")[0].data("test");
```